# Syncronizing backbone with pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, pusher

I am writing an application using backbone + rails.
The application allows users to create tickets, and show these tickets in real-time for all other users using real-time service [pusher](http://pusher.com/).

My problem is that when a user creates a ticket I add it to the collection:

```
addTicket: function( newTicketData ) {
  var newTicket = new app.Ticket( newTicketData );
  this.collection.add(newTicket, {merge: true});
  newTicket.save(null, {
    wait: true,
    success: this.addTicketSuccess,
    error: this.addTicketError
  });
},
```

The pusher listener code:

```
channel.bind('new_ticket', function(data) {
  var ticketDataObj = jQuery.parseJSON( data.content );
  app.ticketsView.addTicket(ticketDataObj);
});
```

In this point the new model has a **cid** but not an **id** from the database, which might be obtained in the `addTicketSuccess` callback.
On the other hand, the server sends a pusher signal in the `create` action which sends the new ticket with its **id**, but without **id**.

The result is two different models in the collection which represent the same object, one with **cid** and other with **id**. I am aware to the race-condition and looking for nice and robust solution.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **cid** is a client id and is never send to the server.

When Backbone model save is called successfully the data received from the server are set on the same object, not creating another model.

---

So your are manually adding the two models to your collection, try to remove this line :

```
channel.bind('new_ticket', function(data) {
  var ticketDataObj = jQuery.parseJSON( data.content );
  // create a new method addAndMergeTicket
  app.ticketsView.addAndMergeTicket(ticketDataObj);
});
```

In this new method, before you add the model to the collection, iterate through the collection models and if you find that it already exists don't add it again

Comment: Yes, I know. My problem is that the backbone application receives the object twice - once in the `save` callback and one through the `pusher` signal (which obviously does not have the cid).  
This is the reason why I have two objects - one with __cid__ and the other with __id__.  
Important thing - it is impossible to know which is executed first - **save callback** or **pusher signal callback**.

Comment: Just did, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: No, not good. Maybe I didn't explain it well. The pusher callback is called WHENEVER A NEW TICKET IS ADDED. Might be same user, might be somebody else. This is why this callback should call `addTicket`. AS far as I see this callback cannot know if same user provoked this call or some other user.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this time that I understood your problem :)

Comment: Just one thing - since it is possible that the pusher callback will be called first (strange but might happen) I need to call __always__ the new method `addAndMergeTicket`.

Comment: Yes, or you can remove the `wait: true,` when you call `newTicket.save`

Comment: When you do `var newTicket = new app.Ticket( newTicketData );` Backbone generate a new __cid__ for you

Comment: What I meant that if I remove `wait: true` I don't have the id from the database in the callback, isn't it?

Comment: No, even if you remove the `wait: true` your method `success: this.addTicketSuccess` will be executed but asynchronously.